# AWS CDK: Assigning DB Instances to Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When I use CDK to create a `DatabaseCluster` object, the cluster is automatically populated with two `DatabaseInstance`s, numbered 1 (read-write) and 2 (read-only).

I want to explicitly name these two instances (like "blah-rw" and "blah-ro") and am told by AWS CloudFront support that I'd need to create the DatabaseInstance objects separately, then assign them to the cluster.

Question: How do I assign a DatabaseInstance to a DatabaseCluster (or vice versa)?

- The [DatabaseCluster documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseCluster.html) (and its Props object) don't seem to have any fields that accept instance references...
- ... and the [DatabaseInstance documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseInstance.html) (and its Props object) don't seem to have a field that accepts a cluster.

I feel as though I'm missing something here.

Thank you

Comment: I believe you meant "CloudFormation" support and not "CloudFront" support. Somewhat, I can't edit.

Comment: Oops. I did mean "CloudFormation". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a communication from the CloudFormation team. I wanted to explicitly denote which of my instances was RW, and which was/were RO.

However, there are two problems:

- There is no automated way to specify suffices for instances as they are created (other than the auto-assigned numbers)
- Even if I did, one CANNOT assume that the instances' RW/RO statuses will remain static. Any server can assume a RW status if the RW instance fails.

... so basically what I wanted to accomplish is rendered moot.

I'm not going to try to restrict access to certain DB instances by RW/RO status. I'll instead simply restrict RW/RO access through IAM Roles.

Thanks all who've contributed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [CfnDBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.CfnDBInstance.html) and [CfnDBCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.CfnDBCluster.html). The `CfnDBInstance` allows for a `dbClusterIdentifier` property which would attach the instance.